# Will Devuan/Debian run comfortably on a Core Duo with 4GB of RAM?

Tags: system-installation, devuan

I need to install a Linux system I will not provide support for, on an old laptop that's going to be donated. It has a Core Duo T3400 processor (2-core, 2.16 GHz), 4 GB of RAM, and a 320 GB HDD (and a noisy fan... )

If it were a 2 GB machine, I would probably install anti-X on it. But with 4 GB... would it be responsive enough and bear the load of a (64-bit) Devuan installation? And if so - shall I choose a more lightweight window manager, or will XFCE4 or Cinnamon be ok?

PS - If you only have experience with Debian, that would also be acceptable as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

.

Note that if these 4 GB of RAM actually are visible to the operating system, that's done through PAE (physical address extension), and a process can still only access a 32 bit, i.e., 2GB sized, address space.

> But with 4 GB... would it be responsive enough and bear the load of a (64-bit) Devuan installation?

You can't install 64 bit software on a 32 bit system. So that's impossible, and has nothing to do with load!

You can compare a 2 GB-equipped 32 bit system to a 4 GB-equipped 32 bit system.

Hm. Sure, now your system doesn't need to swap if, say, your browser uses 1.5 GB of RAM, your desktop environment 250 MB and now your word processor exceeds 250 MB… but frankly, the more realistic problem is that your browser will want more than 2 GB of RAM, and you can't fulfill that need either way.

So, in your position, the additional 2 GB of physically available RAM might help if the laptop is only used for multiple low-RAM workloads, and for such alone, but as soon as one process, and in a day-to-day laptop, that's going to be the browser, needs more than 2 GB of address space. And that happens quite quickly. It's not even 2GB of actually used pages backed by physical memory, it's 2 GB of virtual address space, where all the things – memory allocators for the loads of concurrently executing tabs, shared memory for even minimally performant graphics, buffer spaces exchanged with network subsytems, virtual machines for JS and WASM, and a lot more resides.

So, since you're asking for experience: 2 GB of RAM was very little for a desktop machine browsing using firefox in 2012, and the desktop manager really doesn't matter much here, as you're limited by the per-process limit of 2 GB on a 32 bit processor. A 32 bit machine running a browser will not feel good in 2023.

Debian and user of window managers slimmer than XFCE4 and cinnamon experience that you asked for: It's probably a bit of a waste of energy trying to make a system that you won't support, anyways run with an unreasonably slim distro – you make this sound like you're giving it to someone non-technical, and while the intent is great, and I'm sure they will have a different amount of patience than I would have for these things, you might not *actually* be doing them a favor if you make the system (which runs like molasses anyways) work "slightly" faster, but instead need a lot of very hm, spartanic interfacing.

Sure, not having XFCE4 run in the background saves several MB of RAM, but at what cost? At the cost of someone who's just been given a leftover laptop, so probably someone who's not been growing up with Linux, learning how to type `dmesg` to find the USB drive they just plugged in, followed by `sudo mount /dev/somethin /mnt`, and then not having great integration for unmounting, desktop notifications, no well-integrated sound control? Are you really doing them a favor? Will you be still have done them a favor when the aged HDD finally loses the data they had?

It might be time to call a spade a spade: While that certainly was a sensible machine 2007 to 2009, it's anemic by any reasonable standard today – because no matter how many of the comparatively few MB of RAM and CPU cycles you remove from your desktop environment, the workloads of 2023 are simply going to be overwhelming for that device. I admire you setting this up for something else, as I would admire helping an old person carry home their groceries. But it's OK to say "I'd love to help you carry home these groceries should you buy them, but it's all just a sludge of rotting cabage, that is a waste of your fridge and my time; can I help you buy pick better produce?". And that would quite possibly help the person more than putting decaying cabbage into their kitchen. To close that metaphor, I don't know the prices for used hardware where you are, but here in Germany, there's multiple sellers that offer used, overhauled, reliable devices. For example [this](https://www.lapstore.de/f.php/shop/lapstore/f/1495/lang/en/kw/Notebooks/?pg=1&srt=prca&uprice=74.25&vprice=9999.00&ckatego_refur=1&ckatego_zusb=1&ckatego_zus1=1&ckatego_best=1&ckatego_Gebr=1&udisplay=11.60&vdisplay=17.30&udisplreso=1049088.00&vdisplreso=9216000.00&ucpucpuclk=1000.00&vcpucpuclk=3300.00&uram=0.00&vram=65536.00&uhdd=32768.00&vhdd=2048000.00&inter=true#searchresult) shop sells used business laptops, which definitely run a modern Linux, and are quite feasible as surfing, text editing, light photo editing, CAD work … in essence: as universal machines, unlike your laptop.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke - that CPU actually seems to support x86_64. I just checked...

Answer (score 0):

Devuan is not an especially lightweight distro. It is just Debian with a different `init` system, and Debian is no lightweight.

So, no. If you want a lightweight Debian-based distro, look elsewhere. Devuan is not the answer.

I enjoy experimenting with low-end machines, and I'd suggest the Raspberry Pi Desktop. It's the x86 PC version of the Raspbian distro. It's currently Debian 11.7 with LXDE and a lot of trimming.

If installed on a 64-bit capable processor, you get a 64-bit kernel, but an almost entirely 32-bit userland, which is sensible as it uses less RAM.

Failing that, look at hand-crafting an installation of Alpine Linux.

Comment: +1 Because I had never considered Raspberry Pi Desktop as an option. But - can you elaborate regarding the "trimmings"?

Comment: Honestly, no. It fits into about 6½ gigs of disk and uses only about 200MB of RAM at idle. How they did that, I don't know, but when I added Xfce to my system, for instance, my RAM usage tripled.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr: The 64-bit version will not run comfortably, although not from the reasons you might expect.**

I have now installed Devuan 64-bit on the machine, and tried it out (with XFCE; may try other desktop environments soon).

The memory usage is a few hundred MBs. It rises if you open a browser, but still not a problem, unless perhaps you use many tabs and a one or two other memory-heavy apps. So, memory usage is an issue, but not much of an issue - plus, specific app mem usage is not really dependent on the OS distribution. (It may depend on 32-bit vs 64-bit though.)

CPU usage also doesn't seem to go through the roof, although I've not tried to stress it.

The thing is, that even before opening heavy apps and applying resource "stress" - the system exhibits slugishness. It takes a loooong time just for the desktop to load after I've passed the lightdm's login screen. Not a fun experience.

I now want to try something lighter, like antiX perhaps, and see whether the experience with it is smoother.

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience, I would choose Devuan 4 Chimaera (not Devuan 5 Daedalus) with LXDE as desktop. GNOME and KDE are too heavy and Xfce and MATE are OK, but heavier than LXDE. LXDE is modular, has very few dependencies and consumes minimal CPU, RAM and disk space. The meta-package lxde-core installs minimal LXDE desktop and the meta-package lxde installs full LXDE desktop. Debian 11 Bullseye (the base of Devuan 4) with LXDE is also acceptable choice. For minimal installation use the "devuan_chimaera_4.0.0_amd64_netinstall.iso" https://files.devuan.org/devuan_chimaera/installer-iso/devuan_chimaera_4.0.0_amd64_netinstall.iso

Answer (score -1):

I've had experience with Debian in the past on a 4GB machine, and even Debian in a VMware Workstation installed on that 4GB machine.
Those 4GB should be enough to use the machine with a web browser and some basic tools.

However I should mention that while you can install a 32bit OS on a 64bit computer, you **cannot** do the reverse, so you should search for a compatible OS.

Moreover, if you are going to donate the PC without support, I would suggest you look into a more conventional Linux distribution as it is unlikely that someone receiving the PC will have any knowledge about Linux, and even less about a Systemd-free version that seems built for tinkerers. While there is nothing fundamentally wrong with that, most people expect from their laptop to "just work" so that should be your main focus.

Regular Debian 32bits with LXDE or GNOME should do just what you need because the first resembles an old windows, and the latter provides a more user-friendly experience.

[Debian](https://www.debian.org/distrib/),
[LXDE](https://wiki.debian.org/LXDE)

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke - that CPU actually seems to support x86_64. I just checked... anyway, definitely not going to subject people to GNOME, that's horrid and cruel. But thanks.

Comment: but to AntiX with Fluxbox/IceWM? Maybe actually check with them what they would prefer after working with it for 5 minutes. I don't mean that negatively at all, @einpoklum, but your taste seems to differ very much from that of the "common person on the street", and pushing something fast and practically unusable on something rather than something that you consider slow and horrible, but is understood intuitively by many people, might be doing someone a disservice.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: AntiX with Fluxbox/IceWM if the machine is too slow to support something else, not because it's a super-friendly UI. The common person on the street would take a minimalist responsive UI over a UI which lags. Anyway, GNOME is infamous for being un-intuitive and user-unfriendly, so definitely not that.

Comment: honestly, I think you need to talk to the people you're doing this for. I come to a very different conclusion what people really want than you! Gnome might be known in *your* circles to be unintuitive, but any newbie that I helped with would prefer modern GNOME by far over things like fluxbox. Very, very solidly. It's no sense that we express a difference of opinion here – ask the person who has to use this afterwards. Not like it's a problem to install both and let them choose, costs no performance at all.

Comment: I am speaking from personal experience here, I know what my impressions were when I first tried Linux, and when I first tried GNOME it was a relief compared to XFCE.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to walk away from support and have a system that works adequately in 4GB RAM there's one other choice that if it works will keep itself up to date and look modern.

Give ChromeOS Flex a try.
Linux based, low resource requirements and backs up your work to the Google account so when that machine does die it can be replaced with something similar or a £50 second hand Chromebook.

Comment: "And backs up your work to Google" already disqualifies this, before I even considered anything else.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, It should run fine depending on the DE and the used software packages. I'm currently writing from a 10-15 years old computer which has a Core 2 Duo E5700 CPU, 2 gigs DDR2 ram, a GT610 GPU (just for playing videos on YouTube) and a 120 gigs SSD. Linux is very flexible and while I'm idle on the desktop my system consumes about 200-250 megabytes of RAM. When I open Firefox-ESR it goes up to 700-800 or more, depending on the number of tabs. If I switch to NetSurf browser then the ram usage is WAY less... I can also play HD videos on YouTube.

I use a mixture of Devuan, Openbox, LXDE and XFCE with lightweight but usable software packages. Linux is amazing, this system consumes as much ram as Windows XP did in the past and it's 2023. This PC is still usable and not in the trashbin.

Recommended lightweight Debian and Devuan packages:

Openbox, LXDM, Htop, LXtask, Lxpanel, Xterm, AbiWord, Gnumeric, Galculator, L3afpad, Xpdf, XFCE4-Settings, XFCE4-Screenshooter, ImageMagick, Audacious, VLC, Kazam, Gparted, PCManFM, Xarchiver, Xfburn, Psensor, Transmission, Hexchat, Pidgin, Midnight Commander, Claws Mail (can make Gmail works), NetSurf. On my PC I can also use Thunderbird and Firefox-ESR which is a huge improvement in the meaning of comfort, but they are both RAM eaters...

This was my setup at the afternoon: https://imgur.com/a/w5qyqOy. I changed Tint2 to Lxpanel and LightDM to LXDM to make it even more lightweight.

Take in note that single core CPUs are painful for browsing, two cores are the bare minimum.